# Getting a 404 error when trying to setup contact form using nextjs and nodemailer

Tags: typescript, next.js

Im getting the following error when trying to setup a contact form using nodemailer:

POST http://localhost:3000/api/send-email 404 (Not Found)

and

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config

Here is my directory tree: [file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c4iS.png)

and my send-email.ts file:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).end(); 
  }

  const { email, subject, message } = req.body;

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, 
    auth: {
      user: 'myemailaddress', 
      pass: 'password', 
    },
  });

  try {
    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: 'myemailaddress', 
      to: email,
      subject: subject,
      text: message,
    });

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Email sent successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error sending email' });
  }
}
```

and my page.tsx file inside of a contact-us folder for routing:

```
'use client'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ContactUs = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await axios.post('api/send-email', { email, subject, message });
      alert('Email sent successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert('Error sending email');
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">
      <div className="py-8 lg:py-16 px-4 mx-auto max-w-screen-md">
        <h2 className="mb-4 text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-center text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Contact Us</h2>
        <p className="mb-8 lg:mb-16 font-light text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 sm:text-xl">
          Got a technical issue? Want to send feedback about a beta feature? Need details about our Business plan? Let us know.
        </p>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="space-y-8">
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="email" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">
              Your email
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              className="shadow-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
              placeholder="name@flowbite.com"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="subject" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">
              Subject
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="subject"
              className="block p-3 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500 dark:shadow-sm-light"
              placeholder="Let us know how we can help you"
              value={subject}
              onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="sm:col-span-2">
            <label htmlFor="message" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400">
              Your message
            </label>
            <textarea
              id="message"
              rows={6}
              className="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg shadow-sm border border-gray-300 focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500"
              placeholder="Leave a comment..."
              value={message}
              onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="py-3 px-5 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white rounded-lg bg-primary-700 sm:w-fit hover:bg-primary-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800"
          >
            Send message
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default ContactUs;
```

I tried playing around with the directory tree but nothing worked.

Comment: I think you’re just missing a `/` in front of api in `await axios.post('api/send-email'`